# New object creation concurrent with method call

Tags: c#, .net, syntax

In the following code, it seems a new object is created while concurrently calling a method (`Resize`) on that object:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(fileNameTextBox.Text).Resize(400, 400, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR, true);
```

Is what I described the correct interpretation of what is happening? What is the name in the C# world for this type of usage?

Comment: Not concurrently - it's happening in sequence. And it's called method chaining, usually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not doing it concurrently at all. It creates the object, then calls the method - and then assigns the result of the method call to the variable. So it's equivalent to this:

```
var tmp = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(fileNameTextBox.Text);
Image<Bgr, Byte> img = tmp.Resize(400, 400, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR, true);
```

There's no specific name for this - it's reminiscent of the builder pattern, although it's not clear from your example whether `Resize` modifies the existing object and returns `this`, or whether it creates a *new* object with the appropriate resize operation performed.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a special name for this type of shortcut where one statement resolves to multiple statements behind-the-scenes?

Comment: @Sabuncu: It's not really that it "resolves to multiple statements" - it's *equivalent* to that, but you don't need to think of it that way... and you could go further by extracting the `fileNameTextBox.Text` evaluation to a separate statement if you really wanted to.